# list comprehension with np.where to compare two arrays and combine them it first entry is equal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to have an array "set1" which consist in the first four rows of the array "a" and then if the first value/element of a row is the same of "a" and "d", there comes another distinction depending on the second value of "d":

- If the second value in a row of "d" is =**1** -> third value of "d" in a
  row is writen in "set1" at the **fouth** element of the row
- If the second value in a row of "d" is =**2** -> third value of "d" in a
  row is writen in "set1" at the **fifth** element of the row
- If the second value in a row of "d" is =**3** -> third value of "d" in a
  row is writen in "set1" at the **sixth** element of the row
  One Value at the first position of "a" occurcs between 0-3 times in "d"

I have so far:

---

```
a=np.array(([5,2,3,4],[3,22,23,24],[2,31,32,34],[1,41,42,44],[4,51,52,54],[6,61,62,64]))
d=np.array(([2,3,5],[4,1,4],[2,1,2],[5,3,1],[6,2,44],[5,1,3],[1,3,55],[1,1,6]))
set1= np.zeros((a.shape[0],a.shape[1]+3),dtype="int")
set1[:,:4] = a[:,:]
for i in (set1[:,0]-1):
     j=np.where(d[:,0]==set1[i,0])
     if len(j[0])==1:
        if d[j[0],1]==1:
           set1[i,4]=d[j[0],2]
        elif d[j[0],1]==2:
           set1[i,5]=d[j[0],2]
        elif d[j[0],1]==3:
           set1[i,6]=d[j[0],2]
print(set1)
```

---

My Code works only if there is only **one** occurence of the same number of the first element (In this case only the last row of set 1"6 61 62 64 0 44 0" is displayed correctly). In all other cases the desired output is not archived.
For instance the fith row is displayed:

```
[5 51 52 54 0 0 0]
```

instead of the desired

```
[5 51 52 54 3 0 1]
```

Is there a more "pythonic" way to do this? Compare the first element and combine elements them according to the rule above (1 --> 4th element , etc.)?

[edit] changed numbers to avoid confusing ID with indices

Comment: I'm having some trouble following your example, and when I run your code the result doesn't appear to match the description of your desired results. Nevertheless, it seems that you should be able to do what you'd like using the basic indexing patterns in numpy (see: [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html)). As an aside, if this is your actual data you might want to consider a different representation, because there is a whole lot of redundancy and repetition of values.

Comment: I tried to make the problem clearer. CAn you follow it now better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two columns of `d` are the indices into `set1` at which you want to place the values in the third column of `d`, after a small correction. From there, it's as simple as using the indexing patterns I linked to in my comment.

Full example:

```
a=np.array((
        [1,2,3,4],
        [2,22,23,24],
        [3,31,32,34],
        [4,41,42,44],
        [5,51,52,54],
        [6,61,62,64]))

d=np.array((
        [2,3,5],
        [4,1,4],
        [2,1,2],
        [5,3,1],
        [6,2,44],
        [5,1,3],
        [1,3,55],
        [1,1,6]))

# allocate the result array
m, n = a.shape
res = np.zeros((m, n+3))
res[:m, :n] = a

# do the work
i, j, values = d.T
res[i-1, j+3] = values
```

Such that

```
>>> res
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   6.,   0.,  55.],
       [  2.,  22.,  23.,  24.,   2.,   0.,   5.],
       [  3.,  31.,  32.,  34.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  4.,  41.,  42.,  44.,   4.,   0.,   0.],
       [  5.,  51.,  52.,  54.,   3.,   0.,   1.],
       [  6.,  61.,  62.,  64.,   0.,  44.,   0.]])
```

---

### If the first column of `d` are not indices...

In the general case where the first column of `d` are not indices, you'll need to look up the location of each entry of `d[:,0]` in `a`. The fastest way to do this asymptotically is with a hash table, but in practice a sufficiently fast way to do this is to use `np.searchsorted`:

```
a=np.array((
        [5,2,3,4],
        [3,22,23,24],
        [2,31,32,34],
        [1,41,42,44],
        [4,51,52,54],
        [8,61,62,64]))

d=np.array((
        [2,3,5],
        [4,1,4],
        [2,1,2],
        [5,3,1],
        [8,2,44],
        [5,1,3],
        [1,3,55],
        [1,1,6]))

# allocate the result array
m, n = a.shape
res = np.zeros((m, n+3))
res[:m, :n] = a

# do the work
i, j, values = d.T

ids = a[:, 0]
sort_ix = np.argsort(ids)
search_ix = np.searchsorted(ids, i, sorter=sort_ix)
id_map = sort_ix[search_ix]
res[id_map, j+3] = values
```

Such that

```
>>> res
array([[  5.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   3.,   0.,   1.],
       [  3.,  22.,  23.,  24.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  2.,  31.,  32.,  34.,   2.,   0.,   5.],
       [  1.,  41.,  42.,  44.,   6.,   0.,  55.],
       [  4.,  51.,  52.,  54.,   4.,   0.,   0.],
       [  8.,  61.,  62.,  64.,   0.,  44.,   0.]])
```

**Note**: If `d[0, :]` has contiguous integers `1, ..., n`, but not necessarily in order, then you can avoid sorting and just use a direct lookup table. Replace the bit after the comment above with:

```
# do the work
i, j, values = d.T

ids = a[:, 0]
id_map = np.zeros_like(ids)
id_map[ids-1] = np.arange(len(ids))

res[id_map[i-1], j+3] = values
```

Comment: What if the first colum of `d` is not the indices but rather the ID, in such a way that the first entry of the row in `d` has to be equal to the first entry of `set1` . It was just my example that the entries where by accident equal to the indicies. For the 2nd task it work as a indicies, that is true. thank you for help with code and refining my question!

Comment: Thank you for the complete explanation! What approach would you recomment to actually "think more in" list comprehension and indexing? Because I just get started with python and numpy and still admire the simplicity of solution and now can retrace each step, but coul not wrap my head around it to actually get there on my own. I had some tries with `np.searchsorted`, but without the `np.argsort` first.

Comment: To your Note: `a` is contiguous, but not starting with `1`but something with `413001` and `d` is not contguous, just a sub-set of `a`